# How to convert UpdateResult from MongoDB C# Driver to JSON

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson

Providing some contextual information: I want to integrate some technology with MongoDB using the official C# driver, but due some limitations I need to integrate it using only JSON strings. So, I'm building a simple wrapper to the native functions to call they by passing and receiving JSON as simple strings.

Example of the `find` method:

```
public string find(string json)
{
    BsonDocument query = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
    var list = Collection.Find(query).ToListAsync().Result;
    return list.ToJson();
}
```

P.S.: I know the performance implications of using an async method as a synchronous one, but I have no choice.

This works pretty well, the problem is with the update/replace method:

```
public string updateMany(string jsonFilter, string jsonUpdate)
{
    BsonDocument filter = BsonDocument.Parse(jsonFilter);
    BsonDocument update = BsonDocument.Parse(jsonUpdate);
    UpdateResult r = Collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update).Result;
    return r.ToJson();
}
```

This returns the string: `{ "_t" : "Acknowledged" }`, which only tells me the class of the `UpdateManyAsync()` result. That class expose some properties like `MatchedCount` and `ModifiedCount` that I would like to put on JSON too, but the default serializer is ignoring them by some reason (those properties are read-only, so should be ignored on deserializing, but not on serializing).

I tried to use `r.ToJson<UpdateResult>();` and `r.ToBsonDocument<UpdateResult>();`, but got the same result.

I saw that `toJson()` has some overloads receiving a `JsonWriterSettings`, an `IBsonSerializer` and a `BsonSerializationArgs`, so maybe one of them holds some configuration about the subject, but I have no luck searching for it.

I think that I could import [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) DLL to see if it serializes all the properties, but I would like to solve it without another dependency.

Comment: I just tried that and Json.NET really serializes the object correctly. Still looking for an alternative without extra dependencies.